# Hide process in taskbar

Tags: vb.net

How to hide process of my application in task-bar in vb.net ?  i have tried it, but it not successful.

my coding as the following:

```
Public Class TaskBarManager
    <ComImport(), Guid("56fdf342-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
    Public Interface ITaskbarList
        Sub HrInit()
        Sub AddTab(<[In]()> ByVal hWnd As IntPtr)
        Sub DeleteTab(<[In]()> ByVal hWnd As IntPtr)
        Sub ActivateTab(<[In]()> ByVal hWnd As IntPtr)
        Sub SetActiveAlt(<[In]()> ByVal hWnd As IntPtr)
    End Interface
    <ComImport()> _
    <Guid("56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090")> _
    Public Class CoTaskbarList
    End Class
    Public Shared Sub HideProcessFromTaskBar(ByVal PID As Integer)
        Dim taskbarList As ITaskbarList = DirectCast(New CoTaskbarList(), ITaskbarList)
        taskbarList.HrInit()
        taskbarList.DeleteTab(Process.GetProcessById(PID).MainWindowHandle)
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub ShowProcessInTaskBar(ByVal PID As Integer)
        Dim taskbarList As ITaskbarList = DirectCast(New CoTaskbarList(), ITaskbarList)
        taskbarList.HrInit()
        taskbarList.AddTab(Process.GetProcessById(PID).MainWindowHandle)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just set `ShowInTaskbar` to `false`?

Comment: *Processes* don't appear in the taskbar, *windows* do. So like Nico suggests, wouldn't it be easier to set this property for your windows? There are ways of doing the same thing even if it's not your application. Be sure to [edit] your question with additional details if you need more information.

Comment: The declaration for ITaskbarList isn't very accurate.  These are actually functions that return an error code.  Right now your code is missing all error checking, so of course you can't find out why it doesn't work.  Favor the [Windows Api Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), it has nice and well tested .NET wrappers for this interface.